# Change dataTable columns quantity using the ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I want to change the quantity of columns in dataTable using a JSON param recived by Ajax when the dataTable did the call.

So I tried this:

```
var columns = [
        {data: "data1"},
        {data: "data2"},
        {data: "data3"}
    ];

$("#table").dataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: 'controller/get_table',
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                if (json.param) {
                    columns.push({data: "data4"});
                    columns.push({data: "data5"});
                }
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        columns: columns,
        ...
```

BUT I've discovered that the array of columns is used by dataTable BEFORE the dataSrc, so when the function changes the columns array, it's too late.

How can I do it whithout a second Ajax call for the param? Just using the dataTable call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init your dataTable in the ajax callback.

```
$.ajax({
//get your json params
}).done(function(response){
    $("#table").dataTable({response});
});
```

Datatable as a draw() method wich force draw the table on the web page.

You can also do it with promises.